# Mocking Spring Beans for dev purposes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following scenario and looking for the easiest way to address it:
I have a spring bean that is responsible for reporting errors on prod environment. On dev environments I'd like to replace it with a stub.

Ideally, what I'm looking for is something like @ConditionalOnPropertyOrMock annotation similar to spring's @ConditionalOnProperty. Is something like that doable with spring itself or some other libraries?

I went through few dozens of semi-similar questions about tests, but my case is not for tests. I believe it's possible to make it with a single annotation, therefore I don't like idea of adding a configuration class for mocked beans and initializing them one by one using Mockito/CGLIB/Proxy.

**Upd.** Looks like there's no a ready-to-use solution at the moment. It seems that the way to do it how I want would be to implement a `Condition (SpringBootCondition)` and `BeanFactoryPostProcessor (BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor)` in one class. Then reject beans as Condition and introduce mocks as FactoryPostProcessor.
The easy solution at the moment would be to create beans in configuration class and make if/else there.

Comment: Would creating an interface be an option?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yeah, I can make an interface, but is there an option to make a component from an interface/abstract class?

Comment: You should use profiles.

Comment: @AlexandrIvanov my problem is not that I can't turn off/on bean creation. I'm looking for an appropriate way to mock a bean. I don't what profiles can achieve in that context.

Comment: I would use an interface and create a Bean with an empty implementation. You can also use an Optional to declare non-required Beans, apparently.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. yeah, of course, that's an option, I was trying to find a less invasive method to use in a legacy project.

Answer (score 0):

Putting that as an answer, but still, looking for a possibly better solution.

Created a small utility that does what I need.
https://github.com/astafev/spring-mock-bean